# How to show a pictures rectangle after calling get_rect()

Tags: python, pygame

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could tell me how to show the rectangle of an image after calling `get_rect()` on that image

I have done this:

```py
self.sword_rect = sword_swing.get_rect()
self.sword_rect.center = (self.player_x, self.player_y)
```

and want to see where it is on the screen

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use [`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect). For instance:

```py
color = (255, 0, 0)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, self.sword_rect, 1)
```

(`screen` is the surface which is associated to the display)